# Jsoup symbol error

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm writing an IRC bot that is supposed to grab the artist name from this webpage http://whatthefuckshouldilistentorightnow.com/artist.php?artist=e&x=36&y=30 if someone types in !music. This is part of the code:

```
public void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname, String message) {

if (messageIC.startsWith("!music ")) {
        String musicy = "id=\"artist\">"
        try {  
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://whatthefuckshouldilistentorightnow.com/artist.php?artist=e&x=36&y=30").get();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
        }
        String texty = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
        if (texty.contains(musicy)) {
            String artisty = texty.substring(musicy);
            int artsy1 = artisty.indexOf(">") + 1;
            int artsy2 = artisty.indexOf("</div>");
            artisty = artisty.substring(artsy1, artsy2);
            sendMessage(channel, "artisty: " + artisty); // */
        }                      
        else {
            sendMessage(channel, "Something went wrong.");
        }
}

}
```

However, I am receiving an error message at String texty = doc.body().text();. The message is:

"cannot find symbol

symbol: method body()"

Any ideas as to what is wrong or how to improve on the code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are declaring your var inside the try catch. You should either use it inside the try-catch or declare it before. Try this for example...

```
Document doc = null;
try {  
      doc = Jsoup.connect("http://whatthefuckshouldilistentorightnow.com/artist.php?artist=e&x=36&y=30").get();
 } catch (IOException e){}
 // rest of code
```

Comment: I tried this andI am still receiving an error at doc.body().text();

Comment: Have you tried qualifying `Document` to make sure you are referencing the JSoup class and not another `Document` class? (as well as taking the declaration out of the `try` clause as @Amir Raminfar suggests)